# Is std::getenv() safe to call after main returns?

Tags: c++, static, c++20, destructor

Does the standard guarantee that `std::getenv()` and `std::setenv()` have the same access protections as `cout`? For which the standard allows access after main returns, in the destructor (and constructor) of static objects

> Constructors and destructors for static objects can access these objects to read input from `stdin` or write output to `stdout` or `stderr`.

From reading code that seems like it would be called from `std::setenv()`, it seems like it operates on a global variable (as per https://github.com/digitalocean/gnulib/blob/master/lib/setenv.c#L113). So curious if it's required to use the same tricks as `cout`, `cin`, and `cerr` to make them accessible on shutdown.

Comment: There is no `std::setenv`.

Comment: I wouldn't think too much trickery would be needed.  For output streams, you have to make sure the buffer is flushed after all writing is completed.  But for the environment, the only possible cleanup would be to free any memory that was dynamically allocated for it, and the system library could just skip that altogether, knowing that the OS will free all process memory on exit.

Comment: The C++ standard refers to the C standard here.  C standard says it's implementation defined how `getenv` is implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cout` and its ilk are namespace-scoped *objects* in C++. As such, when `main` exits, they will be destroyed. And they will be destroyed in an order relative to the destruction of other global objects over which you have absolutely no control.

Therefore, to ensure that you can interact with these objects during static object constructor/destructor calls, the standard requires that the implementation ensure that these objects remain valid and undestroyed. This statement is *necessary*, as otherwise it would be impossible to access those objects safely during static object constructor/destructor calls.

By contrast, `getenv` is a *function*, not an object. It *cannot* be destroyed. The behavior of a function is determined entirely and only by the standard's definition of its behavior, and that behavior must *always* happen. Therefore, unless those functions are stated by the standard to have different behavior when called within the scope of static object construction/destruction, they will continue to do what they say they do in those circumstances.